# The default property for cells()

Tags: vba, excel

I was under the impression `VBA` had default properties for all its objects. So that if I say `Cells(counter, x)` the default property attached will be `.value`. Additionally, I've always used `Cells(counter, x)` and `Cells(counter, x).value` interchangeably. However, when adding items to a collection via a for loop, I noticed if I did not include `.value` instead of storing the value, it stored the value as represented by the location in the worksheet. Such that if the location were deleted the reference in the collection would be lost. This brings me to two discoveries: 1) Collections can store non-static references, and 2) `Cells()` and other objects do not have default properties such as `.value`.

If anyone can clarify, confirm, and enlighten, that would be excellent.

Comment: Default value often depends on context.  If you add `Cells(c, x)` to a collection, you will be adding a *reference* to the Range object.  If you assign `Cells(c, x)` to a variable *without* using `Set` then it will be the default Value property which gets populated into the variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not all types have a default member.

Any class module can have a default member, by specifying a special *member attribute* (you'd have to export and edit the code file manually to do this, the VBE doesn't expose any functionality for this):

```
Attribute {member name}.VB_UserMemId = 0
```

Only one member is allowed to be a type's default member.

---

You're discovering the nastiness of default members and why they should be avoided.

VBA does a lot of things to "make our lives easier" (e.g. implicit type conversions), and default members is one of these things.

> Collections can store non-static references

I don't know what a "static reference" is, but when you store an *object reference* in a `Collection`, you're not storing a copy of the object but a *reference* to it.

> `Cells()` and other objects do not have default properties such as `.value`.

`Global.Cells` is a parameterized property getter that returns a `Range` object reference; `Range.Cells` is also a getter that returns a `Range` object; there is no `Cell` class in the Excel object model. The default member of a `Range` is a hidden `[_Default]` member that appears to resolve to its `Value`. But then when you do this:

```
Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection
c.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
```

Then you're adding the `Range` reference that `.Cells(1, 1)` returns, and then this:

```
Debug.Print c.Item(1)
```

Will output that `Range` object's value. Yet this:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(c.Item(1))
```

Will output `Range`.

Confusing? Yes. That's why you should always have `Option Explicit` specified, work with variables declared with an explicit type as much as possible, avoid implicit type conversions, ...and avoid using default members.

By writing code that reads exactly as it should behave, you avoid a number of VBA traps, and when you eventually want to learn some VB.NET or C# you won't be lost at all about type safety and explicitness.

Comment: If you define a key argument in your collection `Add` method, you can end up with `c.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)`, which is 2 different usages in the same statement!