# Data on 1 sheet from all another sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a common Sheet with data (sheet1) from all another sheets in the book, using "with" statement.But it goes 1004 error. How to solve it?

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim c As Long
Dim lRow As Integer

c = 1
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = Sheets(Sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(lRow, c + 4)) = Sh.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 5))

    End With
    c = c + 4
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must qualify `Cells` also with proper `worksheet` object

furthermore you may want to place `With Sheets("Sheet1")` out of the loop, since it doesn't change inside it

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim lRow As Integer

    c = 1
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sh.name <> "Sheet1" Then
                lRow = Sheets(Sh.name).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
                .Range(.Cells(1, c), .Cells(lRow, c + 4)) = Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(1, 1), Sh.Cells(lRow, 5))
                c = c + 4
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't produce an error. But still nothing appears on the Sheet1, while I'm running it.

Comment: With Sheets("Sheet1") is out of the loop now, but it doesn't produce anything.

Comment: .Range(.Cells(1, c), .Cells(lRow, c + 4)).Value = Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(1, 1), Sh.Cells(lRow, 5)).Value ' This will get you the values; if you want formats too, you'll have to copy and paste

Comment: That's fine, if it's all good then please give @user3598756's answer a tick. In case you're curious why we needed to add .Value, it's well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866303/the-default-property-for-cells). I'm frequently guilty of the same sloppy coding, because it "usually" just works. Until it doesn't :)

Comment: Thank's for explanation. The tick is yours:)

Comment: Not mine, I don't know @user3598756  from a bar of soap, but he beat me to the Answer with an almost identical solution so he deserves the kudos. Oh, just one more note. You may want to start with c = **0** and use .Range(.Cells(1, c **+1** ), .Cells(lRow, c + 4)).Value. It will even out the blocks of data.