# Why does the return type of Worksheet.Cells function alter with the assignment variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro code.

```
Sub display_name()
    Dim strName As String
    Dim nameCell As Range
        
    strName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) 'String
    Set nameCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) 'Range Object
    
    MsgBox "Content: " & strName & ", " & nameCell.Value
End Sub
```

MsgBox Value:

> Content: Hello world, Hello world

In the first case *ActiveSheet.Cells* method returns a string and in the second line the same method returns a Range Object.

According to the vba documentation, *[Worksheet.Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)* returns a Range Object. I come from a Java background and I find this behavior out of place.

I have the following questions,

1. Why does the return type of *Worksheet.Cells* vary depending on the
   type of the variable to which it is assigned?
2. Why does VBA allow this behavior?

Comment: When not setting as an object, the default return of a range is implicitly `.Value` so `strName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)` is the same as `strName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value`.  also `MsgBox "Content: " & strName & ", " & nameCell.Value` would be the same as `MsgBox "Content: " & strName & ", " & nameCell`  When you `Set` and object it does not have the implicit `.Value` as that is not an object but a string.  VBA guesses what is wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `Set`-statement in VBA, you are assigning an object reference to a object variable. In most languages, you don't have this `Set`-command, instead you assign the reference with `=` or `:=`, but in VBA you have to use `Set`.

If you omit `Set` and try to assign an object to a variable, you will get a runtime error 438. With one exception:

VBA has the concept of *Default member*. Every class *might* have a Default member (not all classes have one!). VBA will implicitly refer to the Default member if you use an object without specifying a member and you are not referring to the reference of that object (e.g. using `Set` or passing an object as parameter when an object is expected).

That *Default member* comes in handy in several circumstances. Take for example a `Collection` where you can access it's members via the index as if it was a simple array. So you write `MyCollection(1)` to access the first member - what you really do is you call the function `Item` that is the default member of the Collection.

That *Default member*, however, might also lead to confusion. If you pass an object as a parameter to a subroutine and the parameter is defined as type `Variant`, will VBA pass the reference of the object or the value of the default member?

If you want to know the default member of a class, go to the Object Browser [F2] and look for the member with a blue Icon. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122859/7599798) explains the usage of it - including how to show hidden members.

Basically, the default member of a Range is ... complicated. However, if the Range contains only one cell, it is the Value of that cell (as far as I know it is the member `Value2`). You will find that more often than not the value of a cell is accessed using the default member - as you did it in your example code. But I would give the advice to write explicitly `strName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value` - leaves no room for misunderstanding.

If you are interested in more details, read this [Rubberduck article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/). And here an [interesting Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996772/is-value-actually-the-default-property-of-the-range-object/32997154#32997154) about the *real* default member of a Range. And if you are still not confused enough, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866303/the-default-property-for-cells).